# Run php calculations when the browser is closed

Tags: php, html, paypal, server

I'm trying to create a YouTube-like service where the content creator is paid for their content however I'm a bit stuck.

The website needs to calculate the amount of views a content creator gets a month to calculate how much they need to be paid and then through PayPal API pay them by the end of the month. The problem is that this needs to be done even when the page is closed. I assume this is done on a server but I not sure if that's the case or even how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Try to Google `cron`.

Comment: Yes, this is done on the server and it could be done based on a cron job or something similar. As your title suggests, you cannot "run" php code when a browser is closed, but a server can invoke php scripts at a predetermined time.

Comment: You got ssh access to the server? You got Crontab access? Screen maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Just googling real quick on cron, I found this website: https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html

I have used cron a lot before and the information here seems adequate to answer your question; it at least will arm you with the knowledge needed to do what is required.

An example for a cron job could be the following:

```
50 * * * * /myTask.php
```

What this says is "run this script 'myTask.php' every 50 minutes, every hour, every day of the month, every month, every day of the week" - simply put, run every 50 minutes.

The aforementioned task can be added to the crontabs file by using the following command from the terminal `crontab -e`

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. It turns out that the service hosting my website has an option to run cron jobs internally so I can make a script to loop through all the users, calculate their view earnings and pay them and run it at the beginning or each month.